# is there any method in javascript to genetare hash_hmac code. (Just like hash_hmac in php)

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography, md5

I have the php code to generate **hash_hmac**

```
$concate=array();
$validation_token = hash_hmac('md5', implode("|", $concate), 'hshalslkaslfhalkfhalsksaas');
echo $validation_token;
```

so now `$validation_token` is giving me the correct value. but I want these type of functionality in Javascript.

Can Any One Help Me. ?

Thanks in Advance.:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need HMAC SHA1 encryption library for javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337959/need-hmac-sha1-encryption-library-for-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

there is no default functions but there are third party libarires that provide this functionality

- [Crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) is a good library that provides this feature ( see https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC) for how to generate HMAC codes using this library)

Here is an example

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-md5.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha512.js"></script>
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacMD5("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

Note: The library is not very actively maintained,

Comment: Can you tell me what value I have to pass in First parameter. Please ?

Comment: The first parameter is the message to be converted to a Hash, from your example it the imploded string of a empty array, so basically a empty string, i don't know why you wish to hash a empty string, but equivalent code will be var hash = CryptoJS.HmacMD5("","hshalslkaslfhalkfhalsksaas");

Comment: Hello Manquer, Finally I got it. 10x buddy

Comment: glad you figured it out :)